# Inequality involving $|u|^{p-1} u$

Tags: inequality

For $u,v \in L^q(\Omega)$ with $q \ge p \ge 1$, how does one show that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\||u|^{p-1}u - |v|^{p-1}v\|_{L^{p/q}} 
& \le C\,\|(|u|^{p-1} + |v|^{p-1})\,|u-v|\,\|_{L^{p/q}}\\
& \le C\,(\|u\|^{p-1}_{L^q} + \|v\|^{p-1}_{L^q})\,\|u-v\|_{L^q}
\end{aligned}
$$

Thanks.

Comment: the first inequality is well explained here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9960/complex-inequality-up-1u-vp-1v-leq-c-p-u-vup-1vp-1?rq=1

Comment: ... and the second one is Hölder with $\frac 1q + \frac 1\alpha = \frac 1{\frac pq}$ giving $\alpha = \frac pq + \frac 1{p-1}$.

Comment: Ok, I nearly see it now. Except for the mean-value theorem step...

Answer (score 1):

Just to put something in this box: the "mean-value theorem step" is

> For  all real $r\ge 1$ one has $r^{p-1} - 1 \leq c_p(r - 1)(r^{p-1} + 1)$

Indeed, applying MVT  to $f(x)=x^{p-1}$ on the interval $[1,r]$ we get $$f(r)-f(1)=f'(\xi)(r-1)=(p-1)\xi^{p-2}(r-1),\qquad \exists \xi\in (1,r)$$
Here $\xi^{p-2}\le \max(r^{p-2},1)$ where we take $\max $ because $p-2$ could be either negative or positive. Hence, 
$$r^{p-1} - 1 \leq (p-1)(r-1) \max(r^{p-2},1)\leq (p-1)(r-1) (r^{p-1}+1)$$